# Why $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(\ln 4)^k}{k!}=0.25$?

Tags: calculus

Hi can someone please explain why

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (\ln 4)^k}{k!} = 0.25$$

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor expansion of $e^x$?

Comment: Hint: $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That expression is same as $e^{-ln(4)}$, and this is in fact $1/4$, i.e $0.25$

Comment: most welcome.. @matthias

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$\exp(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
So now
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (\ln 4)^k}{k!} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\ln 4)^k}{k!} $$
$$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln 4^{(-1)})^k}{k!} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\ln \frac14\right)^k}{k!}$$
$$=\exp\left(\ln \frac14\right)=\frac14$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is $e^x$ as a series? Can you express $0.25$ in terms of an exponential base $e$?